# stagehand command not found when trying to create new application

Tags: dart

I just installed [stagehand](https://github.com/google/stagehand) on my mac and the install went off without a hitch, but when I try using it to spawn a new dart application I get this error `-bash: stagehand: command not found`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've looked at my machine, and stagehand is in ~/.pub-cache/bin which I think I had to add to my .profile manually:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.pub-cache/bin`

(edit: I've just found the confirming information tucked away in the `pub` pages: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/cmd/pub-global#running-a-script-from-your-path)

Answer (score 4):

I'm on mac too. I did this:

```
brew tap dart-lang/dart
brew install dart
stagehand
  zsh: command not found: stagehand
```

And then this command fixed it:

```
pub global activate stagehand
```

Now it works:

```
stagehand
  Welcome to Stagehand!
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across same issue on my windows pc. I had to check flutter installation directory and add following .pub-cache\bin directory to Windows path environment variable.

```
D:\flutter\.pub-cache\bin
```

I think this might be helpful to any Windows user.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS run this command: export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Answer (score 0):

I installed it, but still gave me error not found, but I noticed warning in following message after running the command:

```
Package stagehand is currently active at version 3.3.11.
Resolving dependencies...
The package stagehand is already activated at newest available version.
To recompile executables, first run `global decativate stagehand`.
Installed executable stagehand.
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\Nijat\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
You can fix that by adding that directory to your system's "Path" environment variable.
A web search for "configure windows path" will show you how.
Activated stagehand 3.3.11.
```

The problem is this line:

```
Warning: Pub installs executables into C:\Users\Nijat\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin, which is not on your path.
```

Thus, you also need to add that to your environment variables. This solved my problem and now I can run stagehand.